# Windows 10 terminal encoding

Tags: windows-10, terminal, encoding

How can I find out the encoding of my windows 10 terminal? It doesn't display characters right.
I am trying to output unicode characters that it apparently supports but it behaves strangely when running my C++ program.

Comment: What do you mean by terminal? A `cmd` shell?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: @DavidPostill He meant the virtual terminal window, not a shell / command line interpreter.

Answer (score 9):

#### How can I find out the encoding of my windows 10 terminal?

If by terminal you mean a `cmd` shell, you can use the `chcp` command to display and change the code page used.

**Examples**

> View the current code page:
>
> ```
> chcp
> ```
>
> Change the code page to Unicode/65001:
>
> ```
> chcp 65001
> ```

Source [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)

Here is a full list of [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx). See also [Code Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) - Change the active console Code Page. The default code page is determined by the Windows Locale.

Comment: He meant the virtual terminal window, not a shell / command line interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in `cmd` window, make a right click on the black icon located in the top left corner then make left click on "property in menu", in the appeared windows, click on "Font" tab and try different fonts (preferably TTF, such as Lucida Console) that support your unicode characters

Comment: That won't help if he is using the wrong code page ...

Comment: Yes, agree, but incompatible with unicode  font that haven't appropriate characters set could be an issue too, so assume my answer as an addition to your answer.

Comment: He meant the virtual terminal window, not a shell / command line interpreter.